# Is there an alternative to open-xml sdk to generate word documents

Tags: ms-word, openxml, openxml-sdk

I'm trying to generate word documents using open xml sdk. When the documents are small this is no problem (and rather easy). When the documents become larger (+500 pages) I notice the peformance (duration, memory usage, ...) goes down significantly.

Googling this problem I came across [some posts](http://blog.goyello.com/2009/08/27/performance-battle-open-xml-format-sdk-2-vs-spreadsheetgear-2009/) that point out the same problem. For excel there is a solution with [spreadsheetgear](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/?aw=spreadsheetgear).

I would like to know if there is a word alternative to this or if there are other solutions to generate word documents?

Thanks,
Jelle

Comment: I just use `System.IO.Packaging` directly and handle all of the conversions in XML myself. The SDK doesn't really offer me anything I can't do myself.

Comment: I need to merge an xml-document containing data into the word document. To do this I use flexDoc (http://flexdoc.codeplex.com/) to mark the places where data needs to be inserted. This works but it goes really slow. Do you know a better way to do this?

Comment: I don't, other than recreating similar functionality to what flexDoc does. It is using the OOXML-SDK itself, which is likely to make things slightly slower. It's also using XSLT, which can be slow depending on how it is created. Finally, it looks like it is using the Winword client - this is probably what significantly slows it down. Sorry I can't be of more help here.

Answer (score 2):

I've written a blog post series on generating Open XML WordprocessingML documents.  The approach that I take is that you create a template Word document, insert content controls, and then write XPath expressions in those content controls to specify the XML to pull from a source XML data file.  I've also explored another approach where you write C# code in Open XML content controls.  That approach also works.

http://ericwhite.com/blog/map/generating-open-xml-wordprocessingml-documents-blog-post-series/

-Eric

Answer (score 0):

You might look at http://docx.codeplex.com/

On Java, you could use docx4j. If you were brave, you could create DLLs for it via IKVM...

Answer (score 0):

I decided to go with [Aspose Words](http://www.aspose.com/categories/.net-components/aspose.words-for-.net/default.aspx). It is really fast and not very demanding on resources (CPU, memory). It has the disadvantage that it is quite expensive. I also investigated [Softartisans Office writer](http://officewriter.softartisans.com/officewriter-372.aspx). The posibilities are the same but due to fact that the company I'm currently working for already used other Aspose components we decided to go with Aspose Word.

Comment: For future reference, another solution you can try is [GemBox.Document](https://www.gemboxsoftware.com/document), fast performance, easy to use, and much cheaper.