# Word/PDF Generation in C# with hundreds of pages is too slow

Tags: c#, pdf, ms-word

I'm having speed issue generating documentation in C#.

I am basically trying to create documents with 600+ pages.  But the tools I have used handle this very slowly.

I first tried using [DocX](http://docx.codeplex.com/) by Novacode.  Creation of this document with 600+ pages takes upwards to 3 minutes.  I learned that there could be an issue with the function "InsertDocument" so I tried to find a different solution.

I started looking into opening a HTML document into word.  While this is a fast solution, images are not embedded into the document. The HTML syntax (src="data:image/png;base64,xxxx") is not supported in MS Word.

I could use URLs to the images, but then if the internet connection is down, the images would not display.

I then started looking into a HTML->PDF solution. [iTextSharp](http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/) is a little faster than the DocX solution, but still takes 1-2 minutes to generate this document.

I am simply out of ideas.  I'm not sure a commercial product would be better, and I don't want to shell out that kind of cash, to just have the same speed issue.

Has anyone had experience with creating Word/PDF documents with 600+ pages in C# that is fairly quick (1-5 seconds).

Comment: it's not clear from your question what the real goal is.  E.g. using HTML will give you a file with embedded images, but you say it won't open in Word.  So does the output have to be Word-compatible?  In any case, the next logical thing to try is RTF.

Comment: The output PDF is almost 6MB.  But, its not a download speed issue.  It's the generation of the document, before the download begins.

Comment: It's not necessarily the amount of pages, but also how optimized your code is while generating the PDF.  I've noticed a huge drop in processing time when I optimized how it writes out the images, and of course the little stuff here and there, like `string` vs `StringBuilder` that add up pretty quickly.  Still, 600+ pages of images and text in under 5 seconds?  That's a tall order!

Comment: I am open to any final goal that opens a file in either Word or PDF and generates it very quickly.

Comment: Most commercial solutions have either a trial or a money back guarantee.

Comment: Yeah, so try RTF.  It's easy to generate and obviously opens in Word.  I'm not sure how well Word handles embedded images but there is a good chance that it does.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3044653/is-there-an-alternative-to-open-xml-sdk-to-generate-word-documents  I'd recommend using Flat OPC XML (rather than RTF or HTML); there are lots of ways to create it, which is best will depend on your content.

Comment: Can you outline why speed is critical here? Perhaps it's because you want to generate the document in a web request? If so, consider doing it in an offline process, and making it available to the user (web interface, send by email) when it is cooked.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to do this from a web server, you should be careful about resources consumption of this process, since you may run out of memory for example quite easily.

If at some point you decide to consider commercial libraries, maybe you could give [Amyuni PDF Creator .Net](http://www.amyuni.com/en/developer/pdfcreator/features) a try. Amyuni PDF Creator .Net provides a "page by page" mode that saves resources when processing exceptionally long PDF documents. The idea is to save each page to the output file as soon as it is generated, maybe keeping a few pages in memory in case they need to be modified.

Take a look on these links for more details:

- [SartSave Method](http://www.amyuni.com/WebHelp/Amyuni_PDF_Creator_for_NET/Reading_Writing_PDF_Files/Methods/IacDocument.StartSave_Method.htm)
- [EndSave Method](http://www.amyuni.com/WebHelp/Amyuni_PDF_Creator_for_NET/Reading_Writing_PDF_Files/Methods/IacDocument.StartSave_Method.htm)
- [Processing large PDF files](http://www.amyuni.com/WebHelp/Amyuni_PDF_Creator_for_ACTIVE_X/Processing_Large_PDF_Documents/Overview.htm)

*usual disclaimer applies*

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to create a rich formatted DOCX file with 600+ pages in that time frame, but for PDF file I'm not sure... it will probably depend on your document content.

Anyway, I'm able to create a rather large DOCX file with [GemBox.Document](https://www.gemboxsoftware.com/document/examples/c-sharp-vb-net-word-pdf-library/801) in just few seconds (0-4 sec), and PDF file as well, but it does take a bit more time then DOCX output.

You can also convert [HTML to DOCX](https://www.gemboxsoftware.com/document/examples/c-sharp-convert-word-to-from-html/105) or [HTML to PDF](https://www.gemboxsoftware.com/document/examples/c-sharp-convert-word-html-to-pdf/304)  really fast, but that can depend on the HTML content itself.

If possible, you should prefer having well written HTML content that's "printer-friendly", doesn't have too much nesting levels, has optimized images, has single CSS file, etc. Also, if you're providing an URL as an input path then I think it's better to have embedded base64 images then links in order to avoid making additional web requests.

Last, I don't think there is much difference in Flat OPC XML vs DOCX. Basically they both generate the same content, it's just that DOCX file is additionally zipped which is a neglectable performance penalty.